# Ofuscando uma string no código fonte

Tags: java, segurança, ofuscação

Preciso ocultar uma *string* no código fonte do meu programa. Pesquisando encontrei um programador que ocultou a frase "Hello World!" através de uma cadeia de `if` e laços de repetição atrelando tudo a um *array* numérico.

O trabalho pode ser visto [aqui](https://gist.github.com/jorgeatorres/442094).

Pergunto, tanto trabalho surte resultados práticos ou isso é facilmente desfeito?

Comment: Veja isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158820/132

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 3):

Depende. Quer esconder de um curioso qualquer e se for descoberto não tem problema? Então serve.

Quer segurança mesmo? A informação não pode ser descoberta? Então não faz nem cócegas. Isto é extramente fácil de obter se a pessoa souber fazer. Não precisa nem entender de matemática ou ficar gastando tempo achar uma lógica nisso. Dá mais trabalho "proteger" do que desproteger.

Segurança é algo difícil e normalmente só feito direito por especialistas, o que é raro encontrar e mesmo estes cometem erros. Claro que existem algumas regras que podem ser seguidas para o básico e isto significa delegar quase tudo para algo comprovado e dar pouco ou nenhum acesso físico à informação que quer proteger.

Comment: Eu sei que perguntas como estas são comuns, porém as respostas são sempre pouco precisas. Há momentos em que não há como se evitar a adição de um dado sigiloso em meio ao código fonte e normalmente ele estará presente na forma de uma string. Proteger uma variável na memória parece mais fácil do que algo totalmente presente no código. Muitos ofuscadores prometem esconder strings também, mas na verdade não fazem muito além do exemplo que dei.   Infelizmente vejo que não há solução eficaz, apenas terei uma falsa sensação de segurança.

Comment: Se a pergunta não é precisa, não obterá respostas precisas. Não conheço ninguém que precisou colocar um dado sigiloso no código. Conheço muita gente que opta por colocar, mas é diferente de precisar.

Comment: Por exemplo, uma chave pública para manter uma conexão segura com um servidor. Embora chaves públicas não seja algo a ser mantido em sigilo total, vamos supor que o usuário a encontre no código, a substitua por uma chave própria e agora sabe como o meu programa se comunica com o servidor.

Comment: Chaves públicas, como o o próprio nome diz, devem ser públicas, proteger isso não faz sentido.